# laravel vapor is injecting cloudfront cdn url between app domain and vue route url

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, amazon-cloudfront, laravel-vapor

I am using Laravel Vapor to deploy my laravel/vue application and using vite to compile assets.

The deployment is working perfectly and assets are being loaded from **CloudFront CDN** but vapor is also injecting CloudFront asset url (https://a.cloudfront.net) to browser url after main domain (https://example.com) and vue route (/login)

Here is a url that it is redirecting:
https://example.com/https://a.cloudfront.net/login

How do I make it as
https://example.com/login
?

Comment: Can you add the code on component and also your vite/mix configurations and the main file of your vue file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem myself.
The problem was a vue router file:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  .
  .
```

I changed it to

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory('/'),
  .
  .
```

and the problem solved.